# JSON conversion error from java Pojo

Tags: java, json

I have userDTO like below, and 
  I am trying to convert userDTO to json string and calling rest API endpoint from my Controller, but the called rest API end point throws error as **"data" is not valid JSONobject**

```
public  class UserDTO {

 private String userId;
 private String firstname;
 private String lastname;
 private List<Order> orders;
  some more data member plus // setter  / Getters

}
```

**My controller class:-** [converting userDTO to json string]

```
 public class OrderController {

    UserDTO userRecord = new UserDTO ();
     //  userRecord some values here

    final HttpStatus httpStatus;
    HttpEntity<?> httpEntity;
    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);

    String jsonInput;
 // I guess this is the point creating that issue. May be Im doing in wrong way....
    jsonInput = mapper.writeValueAsString(new JSONObject().put("data",userRecord ));
    httpEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(jsonInput, headers);
     // calling the rest API endpoint          
   ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(
                  URL, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity,
                  String.class,someId);
  }
```

**Server Sinippet:-**

```
     public MicroserviceResponse createOrder(@PathVariable("cId") final String cId, @RequestBody final String requestBody) throws Exception {
       ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        requestJSON = new JSONObject(requestBody).getJSONObject("data");
        final String jsonData = requestJSON.toString();
        UserDTO orderSource = mapper.readValue(jsonData, 
       UserDTO .class);
       }
```

**Problem:-**
Called API [server] throws "data is not valid JSONObject. Am i missing something here ? please guide me.

Trying to send below kind of JSON format

```
{ 
  "data":{ 
  "username":"test",
  "orderId": "123097R",
  "firstName":"xydz",
  "lastName":"xyzd",
  "email":"xx@gmail.com"
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the whole stacktrace please? Also since you seem to use Jackson, why do you go through the whole process of converting your pojo to a String manually?

Comment: @Aris; - This is the error thrown in called method. org.json.JSONException: JSONObject[\"data\"] not found.", I am converting the data to string because, please see the server snippet in my post. they are looking for json format starts with "data"

Comment: Look at `123097R` it is string and should be wrapped in `"`.

Comment: @talex. all data is corrected no issues their.

Answer (score 0):

As there are no detailed server logs provided - I assume that the mentioned error is happening at the REST layer.

Please try this - create a payload Java class:

```
public  class RestPayload implements java.io.Serializable {

 private UserDTO data;

 public  UserDTO getUserDTO (){
  return this.data;
 }
  public void setUserDTO(UserDTO data){
   this.data = data;
  }

}
```

And then modify your current rest operation to :

```
 @POST 
 public MicroserviceResponse createOrder(@PathVariable("cId") final String cId,  @RequestBody final RestPayload  restPayload ) throws Exception {

        UserDTO orderSource = restPayload.getUserDTO();
 }
```

**UPDATE:**

You can also play with the raw JSON and modify the values according to your needs.

Try this - the below code shows how to add "data" as a parent object to the UserDTO  :

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonElement userDtoJsonElement = gson.toJsonTree(userDTO);

    JsonObject dataObject = new JsonObject();
    dataObject.add("data", userDtoJsonElement);

    System.out.println(gson.toJson(dataObject));
```

Comment: Is their any way that can i customize the json response.. i meant with UserDTO i need to add "data" as parent object

Comment: You can create another DTO (e.g ResponsePayload) similar to the 'RestPayload' and return it or embed it in the response. Basically, you don't need to deal  manually directly with the JSON serialization and desrialization. Java and your REST provider will take care of it.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution definitely work, but i am trying to avoid embed pojo. Is their way to directly add "data" as parent node for my problem. If no, i can try your suggestion..

Comment: Generating the json manually and then modifying it to add a parent element 'data' is not a clean solution and you will be complicating the code and compromising the performance unnecessarily. And it will be crude solution. But it can be done if you really want it that way

Comment: I have done it finally. by jsut passing the object to rest API. thanks